# Grammar is matching function rule more than required number of times

Tags: javascript, pegjs

Here is a grammar that I used. The action after matching the rule 'Func' is called 12 times for the input string if(diff("col")) instead of 2 times.

Debugging I realised the varible peg$currPos is being set back when parsing the Eq rule. I am not able to understand the exact behaviour

```
 Main = Eq
 Eq = (Ar (('equal'i/'>='/'<='/'<>'/'!='/'<'/'>'/'=') Ar))
      /Ar ('equal'i/'>='/'<='/'<>'/'!='/'<'/'>'/'=')
      /Ar 

 Ar = (Mul (('+'/'-') Mul )*) ('+'/'-')?

 Mul = (Ex (('*'/'/'/'%'/'^') Ex )*) ('*'/'/'/'%'/'^')?

 Ex = __ ('-'__ Main/'(' __ Main __ ')'/Func/Lit) __ /'-'

 Func = __ id (('('__ Main __')')/'('__')') __ {
      console.log(text());
 }

 Lit = (col/charLit/numLit)
       / id:id

 charLit "character" = string:$("'"[^']*"'")

 numLit "number" = $([0-9.]+)

 col "column" = col:$('"'[^"]*'"') 

 id "identifier" = $([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)

 __ "space" = [ \t\n]*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are encountering this is because the `Func` rule is matched that many times.  Unfortunately, some of those matches are part of larger expressions (in the `Eq` rule) that fail.  That's why you see `peg$currPos` being set back.

Maybe try:

```
Eq = Ar (('equal'i/'>='/'<='/'<>'/'!='/'<'/'>'/'=') Ar?)?
```

Comment: Yes i figured it out. Thank you